# Seeking for a universal way to get host IP address inside docker container

Tags: docker

I want to find the host IP address inside a docker container. I run below command inside the container:

`netstat -nr|grep ^0\.0\.0\.0|awk '{print $2}'`

It will returns the router IP address and it works in docker for mac. But I wander whether this command works for all different docker host, like Linux, Mac, Docker-Machine. Is there a common way to get it regardless host OS type? BTW I want to find it inside docker container. I know I can setup an environment when running this container but I want to get it more dynamically.

**EDIT1**

My container is based on ubuntu image.

Comment: What is the base image that you use? You want to login into container in order to know IP? Is it ok with to get container ip from host machine?

Comment: My container base image is ubuntu. And I want to login to the container in order to know the host IP.

Comment: But you already mentioned it works. Do you have any other image of different OS and the command mentioned does not work that you think?

Comment: Yes it works on docker for mac. I am not sure whether it works for other system such as Linux, Windows, Docker-Machine etc.

Comment: "Yes it works on docker for mac" is confusing as you said you are using `Ubuntu`. Can you be little specific of the issue if you are facing on a specific os?

Comment: I don't have issue on using docker for mac. I mean if I am working on Linux, or windows whether I can use the same way to get host IP address?

Comment: The commands you are running inside docker container not related to host OS they related to image version you running. netstat -nr prints routing table and you just finding default gateway which is not necessary host IP address (depends on docker networking configuration)

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks.